# Facebook API doesn't return the field "FROM" of comments, name and picture of author

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm making the following requests

```
page-post-id?fields=reactions.limit(0).summary(total_count),shares,comments{from,message,created_time,like_count,comments}
```

or

```
comment-id/?fields=message,from
```

And I need info of the author of these comments (Name and Picture), but the API is not returning this.
The text (message) and data are ok on return. The shares and likes of post too.

Note: I'm using the **page access token**, and I tested with the user access token too.

I select multiple permissions on the graph explorer to test.

Comment: Is your app live, with all relevant permissions approved? Don’t expect this to work for any users that don’t have a role in the app, while it is still in dev mode.

Comment: Is in development mode.